# How to ask in a polite way?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have applied for a job and my recruiter said to me that he would contact with person X and give me information whether I succeed or not as soon as possible. Unfortunately, I haven't heard from him and I wonder how can I ask in a polite way if he has some information about me ?

I was thinking about this one : Do you have any information from X about my interview ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start your correspondence politely, then ask

> **Could you please update me with any information on** *(maybe too polite)*
>   **Would you have any information** about my interview
>   **Would you have an update on** my interview
>   **Has there been any feedback on** my interview
>   **Have you heard anything about** my interview
>   **Is there any news on** my interview

about the interview, and end it nicely with

> **Kind regards
>
>   Many thanks** *(BrE)*
>   **Sincerely yours**

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure how to finish those sentences. I completely don't understand why should I use would in second and third sentence.

Comment: Just add **my interview**, the headhunter will already know that's why you are contesting them, but you may also want to remind them which company it was with.

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question, but I can't understand why 2 & 3 sentence start with "Would" . Can I use "Do" instead ? What's the difference

Comment: No question is stupid. It is possible to use **do** instead of **would** and both mean the same. **Would** is more polite, but debatable if necessary for a headhunter.

Comment: @Ponb : We frequently use past-form modals as courtesy forms. In Anglo-American culture ordinary indicatives and imperatives are perceived as an imposition on the hearer, and  *would*, *could*, *might* are used to make requests more tentative and less demanding